# Looking for a basic PostGIS viewer to use as basis for own application

Tags: postgis

I'm looking for a rather basic PostGIS viewer. It should be possible to pan, zoom and retrieve coordinate information on mouse click. No need to support coordinate transformations. It should introduce as little further dependencies as possible. Preferably written in C++.

Comment: OpenJUMP is good for that. Install from snapshots https://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP_snapshots/ or release version 1.8 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP/1.8.0/. Use File - Run datastore query and write any valid SQL query into the box. BTW Oracle is also supported through DB Query plugin which is included in OJ Plus, but you must add Oracle driver  ojdbc.jar yourself because of license restrictions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although this isn't really the direct answer to your question, qgis acts as a relatively simple GIS viewer which can access PostGIS. In addition to the main application -- which is a relatively complex piece of software -- the core of the qgis library can be 'pulled out' and used from an application written in C/C++ or (I believe, with some work) Python.

[Tim Sutton's post](http://blog.qgis.org/node/10) on the topic of building minimal qgis widgets is probably a good starting place for this. In order to build a simple widget for viewing a layer, the C code is only 63 lines, including headers + other boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate "pulling out" QGIS core. If it works, that would be great.

Comment: Fur future reference: Tim S. pointed me to this example in SVN trunk: https://svn.osgeo.org/qgis/trunk/code_examples/1_hello_world_qgis_style/

Comment: Which is linked from the post he made, in the 'instructions on how to do this': "This example can be checked out of subversion, compiled and run using cmake like this:" ...

Answer (score 5):

try [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/). Not written in C++ but in C#. Maybe it could be some use to you.

Answer (score 2):

[QGIS](http://qgis.org/) started out as a viewer for PostGIS, and is now a full blown open source GIS. From QGIS there is a very close integration with PostGIS enabling [dynamic views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOhbbEkl4Kg), updateable views and a [DB manager](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html) for working with spatial data building and running queries. Styles for your data can also be saved in PostGIS. Default styles can be set, so when you or another user opens a layer from scratch a default style is applied.

DB Manager:
[image]

SQL query builder:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

try this link but its in vb.net
http://hilary-mushonga.blogspot.com/p/building-postgis-layer-viewer.html